# Small torso cracking

Tags: minifigures, repair

I have a ton of LEGO Minifigures I am putting up for sale on my Bricklink, but I just noticed almost every single figure looks as if there is a crack right under the arm starting at the armhole and ending right under it. It’s barely even there. It looks as if it’s part of the figure. I'm not sure what to do. I just wanted to reach out and see if this part is normal or not.

Comment: Hi Ava, welcome to Bricks SE. I can confirm that many of my figs have cracks as you describe, especially the older ones. However, as it stands, this question needs a bit more clarity as to what you are asking.

Comment: Hi thank you,So basically what I’m asking is can these figures be concerned used condition with out cracks? I just opened a new Minifigure just to see and it seems to have a “crack” too.  Is it just apart of the plastic?

Answer (score 3):

As a buyer on Bricklink I expect used item to have some reasonable wear. However if there any visible or known imperfections they should be noted as this would change item condition from "used" to "damaged". And you don't want to end up in a situation your your customers complaining about wrong condition of items you have for sale and leaving negative feedback. Cracks, tooth marks, a lot of scratches, miscoloration, warping are all considered to be characteristics of "damaged" elements.

From my experience it is not worth selling damaged bricks unless they are very expensive and damage is somewhat manageable.